# Android Studio .compareTo and .equals with strings not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a basic create account system (its my first day using android studio so dont judge too harshly) everytime i test the program it simply defaults straight to else even when the two passwords are vastly different. Thank you all very much for your help in advance.

```
public class CreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

    Button Submit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit_btn);

    final EditText Username_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username_txt);
    final EditText Email_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email_txt);
    final EditText Password_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password_txt);
    final EditText VerifyPassword_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.VerifyPassword_txt);

    final TextView Error_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Error_txt);

    final String Username_string = Username_txt.getText().toString();
    final String Email_string = Email_txt.getText().toString();
    final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
    final String VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();


    Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!Password_string.equals(VerifyPassword_string)) {
                Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");

            } else {
                Error_txt.setText("No Error");
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: try to get the values from edittext inside your button click listener

Comment: are case sensitive aware of that??

Comment: Do they have a default value? You are getting the VerifyPassword_txt just once, at the creation of the activity and I assume it is empty in that moment, so you need to take the value inside the onClick as @AkhileshPatil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the values of your EditText at the time of onCreate it self at which time they won't have any values in them as you might be typing them only after screen is open. So you should do this calculation only on your onclick -

```
Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
final String VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();
    if (!Password_string.equals(VerifyPassword_string)) {
        Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");

    } else {
        Error_txt.setText("No Error");
    }
}
```

So understand the activity Lifecycle here. `onCreate` is called to setup your View as the first method to your Activity. At that time your view doesn't have any user filled data in it. Once the view is populated and you see the UI, then the user interacts with it. So any computation that you need to do after user input, has to be action based(in this case your btn click) and hence try to get the data always at the time of action.

Answer (score 2):

You should add **[trim()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim())**

> Returns a string whose value is this string, with any leading and
>   trailing whitespace removed.

```
Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {

    final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString().trim();
    final String VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!Password_string.equals(VerifyPassword_string)) 
        {
            Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");

        } else 
        {
            Error_txt.setText("No Error");
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

change your `onClick` method to retrieve the values

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
    VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();

    if (!Password_string.equals(VerifyPassword_string)) {
            Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");
    } else {
            Error_txt.setText("No Error");
    }
}
```

**note**

Also try to use java standard naming conventions

e.g.

```
String passwordString = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You hardcode the retrieved values from input widgets during the initialization of the Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

... 
    final String Username_string = Username_txt.getText().toString();
    final String Email_string = Email_txt.getText().toString();
    final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
    final String VerifyPassword_string = 
                             VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();
   ...
}
```

You have the issue for password inputs, but you would have the same problem for email and user inputs.
You should get all of them dynamically.

For example for password inputs:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        if (!Password_txt.getText().toString().equals
              (VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString())) {
            Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");    
        } else {
            Error_txt.setText("No Error");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
    final String VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();
        if (!Password_string.equals(VerifyPassword_string)) {
            Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");

        } else {
            Error_txt.setText("No Error");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes try it now

```
final String Username_string = Username_txt.getText().toString();
final String Email_string = Email_txt.getText().toString();
//final String Password_string = Password_txt.getText().toString();
//final String VerifyPassword_string = VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();


Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         String passwordStr= Password_txt.getText().toString();
         String passwordConfirmStr=VerifyPassword_txt.getText().toString();
         if (!passwordStr.equals(passwordConfirmStr)) {
            Error_txt.setText("Passwords must be matching");
         } else {
            Error_txt.setText("No Error");
         }
      }
  });
```